# Popup overlaying polygon blocks mouseover event in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, events, leaflet, overlay

example code: https://plnkr.co/edit/baMA0hrGq5XgG8Tb

I have a polygon that gets highlighted on mouseover. inside the polygon there is an icon and a popup bind to it.
The problem is: when I hover over the popup, the polygon's mouseout is triggered, thus its **not highlighted** although the cursor is still inside the polygon, I don't want that to happen

What I tried:

1. using the popup `offset` method (documented here: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divoverlay) to control overlay behavior, without success.
2. using a specific `css` styling to the popup to prevent that (by changing the `z-index`), again without success (if I set `visibility: hidden` the popup will be hidden and it wont block the polygon `mouseover` event)
3. *I don't prefer this solution* but I thought to trigger the `mouseover` event (over the polygon) whenever there is `mouseover` event (over the popup)

Is there a way to achieve that without using a plugin?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I'm trying to solve this too - did you have any luck?

Comment: @kodikai actually using pointer-events: none style on the icon and the popup solved the problem.

Comment: @user2401856, smart move, that worked, thank you!